# how do i change a sprite in canvas when i click on an image on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently making a basic canvas based game and I currently have my characters sprite set to a specific image in the directory. on the outside of the canvas i have a couple other images (that are also saved in the directory) that I would like to be able to click on to change the sprite to the image clicked.

I have tried playing around with some onclick funtions but have not had any success.i tried playing around with

`var Player = function(){
    this.sprite = 'images/char-boy.png';
    this.x = 300;
    this.y = 550;
}`

by changing it to something like

`var Player = function(){
    this.sprite = function char_select(){
        var toon = document.getElementById(this);
        return toon;
    };
    this.x = 300;
    this.y = 550;
}`

this is what the html looks like

```
<img src="images/char-boy.png" id="boy" onclick="char_select()">
```

I have never used jsfiddle but i copy and pasted what i have in real quick and came up with this. 
https://jsfiddle.net/tibbs/u2pztuxj/

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried so far, add some code to a jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Your image's `onclick` attribute does nothing as your code is erroneous - the function name is `sprite`, not `char_select`. It also needs to be part of an instance of `Player`.

Try this: (you don't need an `onclick` attribute on the image now)

```
var myPlayer;

//Define Player object
var Player = function() {
    this.sprite = 'path/to/image.png';        
    this.char_select = function(clicked_img) {
        //Set sprite to clicked_img's src attribute
        this.sprite = clicked_img.src;
    };
    this.x = 300;
    this.y = 550;
}      

window.onload = function() {
    //Create a new player instance
    myPlayer = new Player();

    //Add click listener for the image(s)
    document.getElementById('boy').addEventListener('click', function() {
        //Call the char_select function with the clicked image as an parameter
        myPlayer.char_select(this);
    });

    //Add more event listeners as required...
}
```